# JAWS 16 not reading image correctly

Tags: screen-readers, jaws-screen-reader

We are using JAWS 16 as screen reader tool for making sure that our site is accessibility compliant.
We are having site logo on the sites but those logos are not read properly by JAWS.
As per the accessibility guideline we have made the alt="" of image and it renders the properly but when control goes over the logo it reads out the previously read text.

My code is like as follows:-

```
<a href="#main_content" class="sr-only">Skip to Main Content</a>
<a href="#footer" class="sr-only">Skip to Footer Content</a>
<div class="header">
<img tabindex="0" src="/images/logo.png" alt="">
</div>
```

Here when the control goes to the logo image it reads as "Skip to Footer Content Link".

Anyone have any idea why it is reading like this?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you want to get. If you want JAWS to indicate the image, then you should *not* leave the `alt` empty. Fill it in like `alt="logo"`, and JAWS will read it properly.

Comment: As per accessibility we need to make sure that image should have alt tag with value as "" string. Problem here is JAWS is reading previously read links when control goes over the image.

Comment: Why do you allow to focus the `img`? (via `tabindex`)

Comment: Yepp, a good question: in this case the `img` shouldn't be focusable. And, sorry, but it is weird that "per accessibility an image should have an empty `alt`". Yes, it should have an empty `alt` if it is *not* meaningful. If you *want* the image to be read by JAWS, then you should fill in the `alt`.